# Layout position after RotateAnimation

Tags: android, rotateanimation

I'm using `RotateAnimation` to rotate my `FrameLayout` with three `ImageView`'s in it. But after the rotation the layout with its child views return to the start position that it has before animation. How can I make it to stay rotated after the animation?

Comment: this is related to fillAfter, fillBefore and fillEnabled properties. I would use fillAfter="true", i suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the documentation for Animation, especially for fillAfter.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html